# What was the significance of the subplot involving Pavel in Chernobyl?

Tags: plot-explanation, chernobyl

In HBO mini-series *Chernobyl* there is a subplot that spans 2(?) episodes involving a young draftee Pavel, played by Barry Keoghan.

I'd say he's quite a famous actor but in the series he's just shooting stray dogs for a few minutes of screen time.

I can understand the significance of the other subplots in the series but this one eludes me.

What was the significance to this subplot? Was there any relation to real world events?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, there is a connection to real world events: According to the [wikipedia article about the liquidators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_liquidators), there were ~600 000 people "cleaning up" the area including shooting animals, removing soil, etc. - Thanks to those people, all long-term issues with Chernobyl have been rather local. Due to the high number of people involved, this is a big part of the story to be told, and it shows the audience one of the negative consequences (young men killing animals which is traumatizing them for their life) even for people not directly involved in the nuclear catastrophe in the first place.

Comment: It also elucidates the point made about how over a million people have [eventually] died as a result of their radiation poisoning.

Comment: I see reports that over a million people were affected (probably a few million) but I don't see reports that over a million people died. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deaths_due_to_the_Chernobyl_disaster), [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20190725-will-we-ever-know-chernobyls-true-death-toll), [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/outlook/five-myths/five-myths-about-chernobyl/2019/07/05/34eb2506-9214-11e9-aadb-74e6b2b46f6a_story.html), [Times Union](https://www.timesunion.com/tuplus-opinion/article/Letter-Chernobyl-deaths-closer-to-1-million-7521703.php)

Comment: So he is a composite character, representing (together with Bacho and this other guy) people who cleaned grounds around Chernobyl? Just like Khomyuk representing all the scientists who helped Legasov.

Comment: @Möoz Yeah, that’s an urban legend.  With the liquidators, most evidence supports the idea that the Soviets got it right.  That’s part of why they used so many liquidators; they did not allow them to stay long enough to get radiation poisoning.

Comment: "young men killing animals which is traumatizing them for their life". Err... you know about those people called "hunters"? Actually pretty much anybody who wasn't living super-sheltered strictly urban life would hardly be traumatized by killing animals, **especially** knowing exact reason why it was **necessary**. At least in Russia of 198x - I'm not sure how it works in USA today. Also, I'm pretty sure many "young peoples" around the world killed an animal today and will do so tomorrow without any trauma.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: It may be a case of cultural values regarding specific types of animals, as well. In the USA, the rate of veterinarians who commit suicide is 2-5 times higher than the national average. On the other hand, I have met people who work in slaughter houses who could not think of hurting a dog, but would have no problem killing and butchering a cow. Whereas in India, lynch mobs have been known to form over cows being killed.

Comment: @sharur there may be other factors at play than euthanasia (including extreme overwork, huge student loans without a large paycheck, etc).

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Yes, they are **(semi) professional** hunters killing **wild animals** for sport. Killing a dog that just had puppies or a cat that comes to you asking for food and cuddles is completely different experience. Is it necessary? Yes, but definitely also traumatizing for the draftees (who might have never killed anything)

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov this is not an accurate comparison. People who *choose* to hunt are not representative of people *drafted* to hunt. Nor is the "hunt" even similar in nature. Anecdotally, I know hunters myself and they like going after wild animals for the thrill. At the same time they still like and care for animals like pets or other domesticated ones. So, they aren't just cold blooded butchers. Even vets who have to put down animals don't exactly take this task lightly as it's taxing.

Comment: @sharur Wow, never knew about vets' high suicide rates! I wonder, if there is the same trend for intensive care personnel?